# How do I remove an element from a SortableJS enabled UL

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, sortablejs

I want to be able to drag out an element from a [SortableJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sortablejs) enabled unsorted list, and make it disappear.  Can I make the rest of the page a drop target?  Or do I need a second list as a target (I guess I can make it appear when dragging starts).

I am using the JQuery binding.

Answer (score 2):

It appears a new-ish default [plugin](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/tree/master/plugins/OnSpill) implements this exact functionality with the 
`removeOnSpill: true` option.